# how to access cuckoo sandbox from other computer on same network?

Tags: cuckoo

I installed Cuckoo sandbox on ubuntu 18 with windows 7 VM and cuckoo sandbox web interface is running on localhost:8000 . But I want to access it by ip:8000 from other computer. But its not working.How to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here.
It may be necessary to set the ip address of the Ubuntu host in cuckoo.conf
https://cuckoo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/host/configuration/

Have a look here also
e.g. "cuckoo web runserver 192.168.10.100:8080"
https://cuckoo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/web/

Finally check your firewall to make sure the port is not blocked
e.g. sudo ufw status